# Cannot declare variable in MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am having difficulty creating the following trigger in MySQL:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_COMPLETE_REMINDER
AFTER UPDATE ON reminders
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        new_date DATE;
    IF (NEW.complete = 1 AND recurrence <> 'NONE') THEN
        CASE recurrence
            WHEN '1 WEEK' THEN
                SELECT INTO new_date NEW.date + INTERVAL 7 DAY;
            WHEN '1 MONTH' THEN
                SELECT INTO new_date  NEW.date + INTERVAL 1 MONTH;
            WHEN '3 MONTH' THEN
                SELECT INTO new_date  NEW.date + INTERVAL 3 MONTH;
        END CASE;

        INSERT INTO reminders (description, date, userID, complete, recurrence)
        VALUES (NEW.description, new_date, NEW.userID, 0, NEW.recurrence);
    END IF;
END;
```

The issue seems to be occurring where I attempt to declare `new_date`. MySQL returns the following error message:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`INTO new_date NEW.date + INTERVAL 7 DAY`' at line 8

I would like this trigger to create a new reminder record when the `complete` attribute changes to 1. The new record should have a date greater than the original record, depending on the value stored in `recurrence`.

Comment: Your select is the wrong way round it should be _SELECT value INTO variable_ - I don't know if that solves everything. You could also do _SET new_date = NEW.date + INTERVAL 7 DAY;_

Comment: @PaulF You are right, but this does not fix the DECLARE issue.

Comment: What error do you get on the DECLARE - the error you reported was related to the incorrect SELECT INTO syntax only.

Comment: @PaulF `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6`

Comment: Please note you can (and should) edit the question when you have followup information. Code in comments is unreadable (and often gets corrupted).

Comment: Have you changed the delimiter from ;

Comment: Are you sure you set the `delimiter` before trying to create the trigger? The last `end` should probably be not terminated by `;`.

Comment: I hate Stack Overflow search engine. This gets asked daily and I can't find a decent dupe to redirect to :(

Comment: @Shadow, changing the delimiter was indeed the problem. By changing the delimiter to //, I was able to create the trigger.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález there were two issues in the problem though, so not completely duplicate - originally OP reported the SELECT INTO syntax error before the edit to show the error at line #6.

Comment: @PaulF I've done what IMHO makes more sense: revert to original question and upvote your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two corrections fixed the issue:

1. Correcting the order of clauses in the `SELECT` statement (i.e.
   moving `INTO new_date` after `SELECT new_date + INTERVAL 7 DAY`)
2. Adding `DELIMITER //` before creating the trigger

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use a variable you can use a [CASE expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) right in the INSERT statement:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_COMPLETE_REMINDER
  AFTER UPDATE ON reminders
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.complete = 1 AND NEW.recurrence <> 'NONE') THEN
    INSERT INTO reminders
     (description,
      date,
      userID,     complete, recurrence)
    VALUES
     (NEW.description, 
      CASE NEW.recurrence
        WHEN '1 WEEK' THEN
          NEW.date + INTERVAL 7 DAY
        WHEN '1 MONTH' THEN
          NEW.date + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
        WHEN '3 MONTH' THEN
          NEW.date + INTERVAL 3 MONTH
        ELSE
          NULL
      END,
      NEW.userID, 0,        NEW.recurrence);
  END IF;
END;
```

Best of luck.